# NBSP creeping inside mySQL data

Tags: mysql

Actually, I had an excel sheet with few data filled. I exported it as .csv file which I later convert into .sql file using online tools. But when I opened the .sql file using Datagrip I found weird unnecessary "NBSP" words replacing a single character space that was actually intended there. I'll add pictures for better understanding. Thanks in advance.

The NBSP Error

[image: THe NBSP Error]

My Table Properties

[image]

The error occurs wherever there are strings. If there is any better way to directly import my excel to the autoincremented table I have here on data grid, I'd be glad to hear you.

Comment: NBSP doesn't happen out of nowhere... I am pretty sure that you had &nbsp; (which is HTML code for space) and conversion turned it into NBSP

Comment: No, I just copy-pasted the converted the SQL file. It didn't have any sort of NBSP, just "space". But when I paste it here, NBSP creeps in. Can you help me figure it out?